# Replace special characters using Windows batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

I am trying to replace these special characters using Windows batch scripting.

| Existing | To |
| --- | --- |
| `My "name" is XXXX` | `My \"name\" is XXXX` |
| `My name is XXX\X` | `My name is XXX\\X` |

I tried to achieve this through Informatica Cloud. It is not working, so I am trying to create one single code for these scenarios.

Comment: Can you try updating your question so it's more coherent?  Can you give a better example of what search and replace text operation you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to load a file. In that file, a descriptive field is having such special characters. So data loading team want to have such extra characters to differentiate for data loading.

Comment: You should not, unless it's the last resort, (and I mean, after every other possibilty has been exhausted), use a batch file to edit content in a text based file. You essentially have to empty/overwrite from memory, or copy the file, read the copy, overwrite the original, and optionally remove the copy afterwards. PowerShell, VBScript, and JScript are all available ad part of Windows, and should be the first choice for inline editing if doing this via scripting.

Comment: Also, this site is supposed to be where we assist you to fix a specific reproducible code issue, not where you essentially ask for that code..

Comment: @user13771510 - what are you really trying to do?  It seems like you are trying to escape strings for consumption in another programming language or for within a text encoding like json or xml. If you elaborate on the bigger problem, better solutions can be offered.

Comment: Emp_id   Emp_Nbr Description. FIle structure will look like this and the column description will contain such as My "name" is XXXX, My name is XXX\X

Comment: I tried to achieve these special character replacement through Informatica Cloud tool for the last two weeks. So i decided to start trying to do through scripting.. This is where i posted here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try drag and drop your input file over this batch script using regex in powershell to replace the special char :

---

```bat
@echo off
Title Replace Some Special Char
Set "InputFile=%1"
If [%InputFile%] EQU [] echo/ You should Drag and Drop an Inputfile over this batch script "%~nx0" & TimeOut /T 8 /NoBreak>nul & exit /b 1
Powershell -Command "(gc '%InputFile%' -raw) -replace '([\"\\])', '\$1' ^| Out-File output.txt"
Start "" output.txt
```

Comment: I will try and update this thread